# Which is better for performance? And vs AndAlso

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, operators

When writing an If statement, I've always used `And` when needed like:

```
If 1=1 And 2=2 Then
```

The only time I ever used `AndAlso` is if the second condition will error if the first isnt true like:

```
If Not IsDbNull(Value) AndAlso Value=2 Then
```

However, recently I've heard that `AndAlso` is better for performance than `And` as the second condition is only read when the first is true.

In this case, should I always just use `AndAlso`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, `AndAlso` can be faster than `And`, because it doesn't evaluate subsequent conditions if an earlier condition proves false.

`And` is a throwback to earlier versions of Visual Basic.
Most (I hesitate to say all) modern languages use boolean operators that short-circuit conditions that don't strictly need to be evaluated.

e.g. `&&` the and operator for C style languages all perform as `AndAlso`.

Be careful if you've lots of code that use `And` and `Or`, a global search and replace can change existing behaviour, if the second condition involves a function call that has side effects.

I would prefer using `AndAlso` and `OrElse` unless you specifically require the functionality provided by `And` & `Or`

Comment: Cheers for your response. I'll ensure from now on I use AndAlso & OrElse instead of the old And & Or!

Answer (score 4):

Coming from a C and C++ background into VB (V5 initially) it was always really annoying that VB's `and` and `or` didn't short circuit. So the case where the second expression was dependent on the first was always harder to write.

I wouldn't expect to see much of a performance increase most of the time, unless the second expression has significant overhead, short circuiting operators will avoid executing it and thus speeding things up.

But if that second expression is a significant overhead then I would be concerned about side effects which will only be performed sometimes—this will make future maintenance harder and could make correctness harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

When the conditions are also functions:

```
If functionA() And functionB() Then
```

...

```
public shared functionA() As Boolean
  IF A is false THEN log -> return true or false
```

...

```
public shared functionB() As Boolean
  IF B is false THEN log -> return true or false
```

Using `AndAlso` here could be the wrong way to go, because then it will only log B when both A and B are false.