# No converts from string to type boolean but I get the error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
 If txtFirstName.Text <> "First Name" & txtLastName.Text <> "Last Name" & txtUsername.Text <> "Username" & txtPassword.Text = txtConfirmPassword.Text & txtAge.Text <> "Age ( Years )" & txtHeight.Text <> "Height ( Cm )" & txtWeight.Text <> "Weight ( Kg )" & txtAroundWrist.Text <> "Around Wrist ( Cm )" & ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
     'do something
End If
```

I always get the **`Conversion from string to type boolean is not valid`** error in the first line(**`if txtFirstName.Text...`**) in vb 2010.

What do you suggest?

Comment: you mean `And` or `&` both are different

Comment: Pretty sure and was meant..

Comment: I sense that you have confused default and prompt in your UI. Or you have it in for the Name family.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the And operator instead of the & operator.

Comment: Have a plus for being faster than I.

Comment: The `AndAlso` operator would be even better in this case.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree, AndAlso short-circuits so that would be even more correct.

Answer (score 2):

`&` in VB.NET is for string concatenation.

You are probably coming from C/C++/C# world, where `&` means `And`. You can use `And` in VB.NET, or better use `AndAlso` operator (equivalent to `&&` in C#). Like this:

```
If txtFirstName.Text <> "First Name" AndAlso
   txtLastName.Text <> "Last Name" AndAlso
   txtUsername.Text <> "Username" AndAlso
   txtPassword.Text = txtConfirmPassword.Text AndAlso
   txtAge.Text <> "Age ( Years )" AndAlso
   txtHeight.Text <> "Height ( Cm )" AndAlso
   txtWeight.Text <> "Weight ( Kg )" AndAlso
   txtAroundWrist.Text <> "Around Wrist ( Cm )" AndAlso
   ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
 'do something
End If
```

Generally, `And` is used as a bitwise operator, while `AndAlso` is a logical operator. See also:

- [Which is better for performance? And vs AndAlso @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705102/which-is-better-for-performance-and-vs-andalso)

Comment: if used `And` operator, then all comparisons will be executed. `AndAlso` will stop after first `false` result

Comment: @Fabio: So you agree that `AndAlso` should be used instead of `And`? If so, feel free to upvote my answer. :)

Comment: OK, but your answer contains some syntax errors, so I cannot upvote it right now, sorry :)

Comment: @Fabio: You are more than welcome to suggest corrections in comments or by using `Edit` functionality.