# Converting String to Boolean Value .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, checkbox, boolean-expression

I'm making a Student Information System where a student can enter their results and calculate their final grade overall. In the group box "Project Results" students enter their project results out of 50 and their percentage is calculated in `TextBox1`.

However, I want to include checkboxes to suit certain conditions; e.g If `checkbox2` is checked this means the project was submitted 7 days late = 10 % deduction in the final grade. I've completed the following code but am having  a run time error of:

> Conversion from string "TrueTrue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

[image]

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Decimal

    If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) & CheckBox2.Checked.ToString Then
        If TextBox3.Text <= 20 Then
            a = (TextBox3.Text * 100) / 20
            TextBox4.Text = a
            b = a * 0.1 - 0.1

            TextBox5.Text = CDec(b)




        Else
            MsgBox("Please Enter value equal to 20 and below!")
        End If
    End If
```

I'm wondering how I can convert a Boolean value to a String, or even if there is a better of way of completing my task?

Comment: If you switch `Option Strict On` you will see your error straight away as this won't compile. That should give you a pointer

Comment: Hi, If somebody's answer works for you, click on the tick next to it. - It helps other users who are searching for solutions. They can see that an answer to a question has been accepted and may work for them. And of course the person that answered the question gets reputation - And (thanks to @JamesThorpe) you get 2 rep for accepting as well.

Answer (score 4):

`CheckBox2.Checked` is *already* a boolean.  When you add `ToString` on the end, you're forcing it to be a string.  This, coupled with the `&` before it, which is the string concatenation operator, is why you're ending up with `"TrueTrue"`.  What you want is this:

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) And CheckBox2.Checked Then
```

---

Side note: the checkboxes you have there imply that the user should only be choosing one of them (something can't simultaneously be On Time and late, for instance) - Radio Buttons would be a better UI choice here.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, I've also changed Checkboxes to Radio Buttons instead!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line to

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) And CheckBox2.Checked Then
```

or check faster with

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked Then
```

**Why?**

`VB` uses `And` instead of `&` and uses `AndAlso` instead of `&&`.

The [& Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx) in VB is used for forcing string concatenation.

So the line `If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) & CheckBox2.Checked.ToString Then` (if both is true)

Equals `If True & True Then`

And become `If "TrueTrue" Then`

Since there are no auto conversion from type `String` to `Boolean`, so the exception is thrown.

Using `AndAlso` will be a little faster than using `And`,  because it doesn't evaluate subsequent conditions if an earlier condition proves false.

**Comparison between `VB` and `C++`**

```
VB      | C++
And     | &
AndAlso | &&
```

**Note**

@James Thorpe's solution works too, but I suggest using `AndAlso`.

See also:

[Which is better for performance? And vs AndAlso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705102/which-is-better-for-performance-and-vs-andalso)

[Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs)

Comment: While you're correct about the performance, in this situation where something is only going to run once in one calculation, and is done after an `IsNumeric` and is only checking a boolean property rather than doing anything complex, I suspect that the performance difference is never going to be worth worrying about here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, but I think it's something that programmers should be aware of. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs) article.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm just saying that it's not worth worrying about _here_.  It's a good addendum to your answer, but what would improve your answer here would be to explain _why_ the OP should change that line of code.  You've gone straight from "you should do this" without a "why you should do this" to something related but doesn't explain the actual problem at all.